# Issue deploying artifacts on FTP from Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: curl, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set up automated build on Visual Studio Team Services and now I must upload generated files to an external FTP Server.

I added the build step "cURL Upload Files", but it is not working.

I must upload several files and folders where some of them contains space characters. This seems to make things more complicated.

If I do not specify any "Optional Arguments", I get a "curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1"

If I specify -g as argument, I get a "Error: curl failed with return code: 26"

I suspect this is due to the fact I have space character on the file path. I could fix that using the -d parameter.

However, it seems I cannot specify "-g -d" on the arguments I get a crazy error saying the host is invalid. (it mix my hosting name with the username) giving me the impression it is confusing the parameter sequence...

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using "cURL Upload Files" task, you can use [FTP Uploader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=januskamphansen.ftpupload-task) task to upload files to FTP Server.

Comment: Still did not try, but it seems a way to go. Thank you.